# CSS transition (pseudo element, font size, em, IE) not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

The basic idea of [this transition](http://codepen.io/rsolorio/pen/xVOMNN) is increasing the size of the font awesome icon and text when I mouse over.

It works fine in Chrome, Opera, Safari and Firefox, but it doesn't work with IE 11.

The example shows the same transition using px (class test1) and em (class test2); I have no problems using px; the problem is specific for the following scenario:

Effect: **transition**

Type: **pseudo-element**

Property: **font-size**

Unit: **em**

Browser: **IE 11**

```css
.test1 span{
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test1::before{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  content: "\f08e";
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test1:hover span{
  font-size: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test1:hover::before{
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test2 span{
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test2::before{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  content: "\f08e";
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test2:hover span{
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.test2:hover::before{
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr style="font-size: 40px;">
        <td class="test1">
          <span>Text 01</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="font-size: 40px;">
        <td class="test2">
          <span>Text 01</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a known issue in IE?

The most similar problem I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750684/pseudo-element-size-different-on-ie11), which mentions a known issue in IE, but it seems a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I just [stumbled across your question in my own search](http://xkcd.com/979/) and I think I actually have your answer, though I can't find anything that proves it: in my own testing, IE10 and 11 will *stack* ems on pseudoelements. So you've got `.test2::before` set to `.5em` and `.test2:hover::before`, which *in any other browser* (to my knowledge) would mean you're overwriting "`.5em` relative to parent (that is, `.test2`)" with "`1em` relative to parent" but in IE it means "`1em` relative to `.5em` relative to parent", where `1em` relative to `.5em` is simply `.5em` (1 * .5 = .5).

In my own case, I had `.6em` base state, `1.5em` hover, and could get it to behave as elsewhere by changing the hover state to `2.5em`, which is `1.5em` / `.6`. Of course this wasn't a solution, because then everywhere else, `2.5em` was too big. I ended up using `rem`s, which don't stack, and suited my purpose (IE10+). I'm not sure how to get `em`s to work without stacking in IE10+ pseudoelements.